# Best way to protect payment data from form to a payment service?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form which allows my websites' visitors to insert their credit card information. Once they click submit this information is passed to a paying service.
What are the potential dangers of this? I use client-side form validation for the input, do I need to perform  server-side validation as well? What about sanitization?

Comment: You always need server-side validation. Client-side validation is no validation.

Comment: Whatever company is doing your payment processing will have good guidelines on how to securely transfer the credit card data. If they don't, you should be very worried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is that you implement SSL certificates in your server , if you won't it then validate the information in the client side and pass it encrypted to the server side and validate it and save it encrypted on your database.

Comment: But I won't be storing anything on the database. I will just pass the data from the form to the paying service to process the payment

Comment: SSL isn't the best way, it's the **only** way. You cannot securely accept credit cards without SSL. It's not about better or worse options, it's boolean: Secure or insecure. Anything but SSL is **100%** insecure.